# Search objects which have multiple description objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new with Rails and I would need some advice :) I have this:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players, :through => :club_players
  has_many :club_players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clubs, :through => :club_players
  has_many :club_players
end

class ClubPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :club
end

create_table "players", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "age"
    t.string   "nationality"
    t.string   "sex"
end
```

Now I would like to model search engine where users can search players by age and have that defined like this in drop down:

```
Team Seniors
Team Kids
Age [14-18]
Age [19-25]
Age [26-30]
Age [31-35]
Age [36-40]
Retired
```

Or by nationality:

```
American
Indian
French
Mixed
```

How can my search engine look like if user clicks on `Age [19-25]`? Where would be a good idea to define what certain string in drop down represent? The same thing with nationality. For example I need to define somewhere what category `A Team Seniors` represent. I would define that team as a team which has more than 50% of players older than 25 years. So, I need somehow to define categories which are defined from some columns of `Player`.

What would be the best practice in doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would create Tags for each of these categories. Then you could apply as many/little of the tags you want to apply to them. Or you create some look up tables/lists for the different sections like nationality.

For age, you probably need birthday and you could then create an age method to give you their current age.